# Read everything after last defined character

Tags: java

This part of code is reading and replacing specific line in `ini` file.

```
line = line.replaceAll("DBGPS = DBGPS_500.." + ".ecf", String.format("DBBBB = DBBBB_%s.ecf", AWinAps));
```

This part of code `"DBGPS = DBGPS_500.." + ".ecf"` is saying compiler to find that text in `ini`.

As I put two dots ".." after 500 because I can't know what numbers would come there ("." mean Any char) everything works like charm.

Problem is if somebody set version of DBGPS on 50023a or something like that, compiler won't recognise that in text as it reads only two dots and there should be three.

Is there a way to say compiler: "Read me anything after 500 and replace that line"?

```
(example: "DBGPS = DBGPS_500READ_ALL_FROM_HERE_TO_THE_END_OF_LINE);
```

SOLUTION: "DBGPS_500.{2,}, meaning 2 or more characters following the 500. – Andy Turner"

Comment: Like... using a regex? I'd probably just learn regex real quick--they're a pretty useful thing.

Comment: You can use substring method

Comment: `DBGPS_500.{2,}`, meaning 2 or more characters following the 500.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Thank You, that was all I need. Works like a charm now.